# Convert linq query with having

Tags: asp.net, sql, linq

i fail while converting this sql to linq...

hope anybody do it.

```
SELECT Max([PersonalNumber]+1)

FROM TestTable

GROUP BY CalYear

HAVING CalYear=Year(Now())
```

Thanks.

Comment: The GROUP BY clause is useless here... just use a WHERE clause

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check out here --> http://blogs.msdn.com/vbteam/archive/2007/12/18/converting-sql-to-linq-part-5-group-by-and-having-bill-horst.aspx

```
From TestTable in a
Group By CalYear
into CalYear = Year(Now())
```

Comment: -1 "into CalYear = Year(Now())" does not make sense (will remove downvote if you prove me wrong)

Comment: have u checkd the link i have given, that have the proof.

Answer (score 3):

The HAVING clause is there to enable you to filter on the results of an AGGREGATE. In this instance you are filtering on the GROUP column which could just be filtered using a WHERE clause instead.

Therefore you do not need to produce a HAVING clause in LINQ. A simple WHERE clause will do the same.

Comment: So how does he convert it to LINQ?